# Размер изображения по размеру окна браузера

Tags: css, веб-программирование, img

Хочу сделать сайт с прокруткой, где каждый блок является картинкой, при этом картинки могут быть разных размеров и форматов (4:3, 16:9). Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно эти картинки подстраивать под разные экраны. Допустим, чтоб на экране формата 4:3 картинка 16:9 обрезалась по бокам и наоборот для 16:9 изображение формата 4:3 обрезалось сверху и снизу и подстраивалось под размер окна браузера. И можно ли такое сделать через background-image? 
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Через background-image элементарно делается. Вам нужен [background-size](http://htmlbook.ru/css/background-size):cover;

Не понимаю,почему вы не нашли ответ самостоятельно.

Comment: Не совсем, по размеру окна он не вписывает, т.е. появляется прокрутка, а мне нужно чтобы каждая картинка была с размер окна браузера. Т.е. вписывалась по ширине без обрезки и обрезалась по высоте, или наоборот.

Comment: У меня никакой прокрутки не появляется. Скорее всего у вас дело не в картинке,а в блоке,в котором эта картинка лежит. Попробуйте обнулить ему padding,margin и border, если не поможет - выложите ваш код (вообще это стоило с самого начала сделать), иначе можно долго гадать, где же вы там у себя ошиблись